# How to configure Vim so that CapsLock is only enabled in INSERT mode

Tags: vim

I want to disable Capslock functionality in Visual Mode. How can I do that?

Ex:

- In Insert Mode, <kbd>Capslock=On</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> should print *A*.
- In Visual Mode, <kbd>Capslock=On</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> should trigger *append text after cursor* (not *append text to end of current line*)

Comment: Do you still want to be able to do "Append to end of line" with Shift-A?

Comment: Wrong answer :-) That means that the simple remapping trick in @kiddorails' answer is not sufficient?!

Comment: Outside of the scope of Vim but I just remap my capslock key to escape.  I never intentionally use capslock so this worked for me.  I guess if I wanted to enter a long string of caps I could enter them lowercase and then do some madness with `vl<backtick>[~` or something...  ;)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10530185/945456, http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert-mode_only_Caps_Lock, and http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/376 (wait, there's a vi.SE?!)

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean by "append to next character" in visual selection?

In your vimrc file or vim session, do following (for command mode):

```
:map A a
```

If you just meant that selection should be ended and you must be able to append characters at end of the current position, do:

:map <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Bingo!

Comment: Why also change the normal mode? For visual mode, a `:xnoremap` would be sufficient.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Didn't know of it, so thought of this mapping. Reading about it now. :)

Comment: I suspect that "append to next character" means the normal `a` behavior instead of "append to end of line" that you'd get with `A` (which is what would be generated were capslock set).